# DataProvider as Result set with iterate in PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit

I have created `PHPUnit` test with test function that is using `@dataProvider`. Something like this :

```
/**
 * @dataProvider getData
 */
public function testData($id, $name, $data) {
    ...
    $this->assertTrue(...);    
}

public function getData() {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM <table_name>";
    $sth = $this->_db->prepare($query);
    $sth->execute();

    return $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------
// EDIT
// same thing is happening if I return just $sth object as result.
// It's first iterate on each record to collect the all data and after run test func. For example :
public function getData() {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM <table_name>";
    $sth = $this->_db->prepare($query);
    $sth->execute();
    return $sth;
}
```

This is working fine up to some point when test is killed. There is memory issue with this approach because this is loading whole result set before testing is started and it's stays in memory the all time.

Is there build in support in `PHPUnit` for db result set and cursor iteration (fetch)? Or should I remove that `@dataProvider` an fetch data from result set inside test function? I am using PHPUnit vesrion 4.8.15

Thanks

Comment: Just how much data are you fetching to cause a memory issue? Do you really need to fetch *all* the records in your DB for this test? Do you need to fetch any at all? (ie could you run the test with a hard-coded array instead, so you don't have a dependency on the database?)

Comment: @Simba, I must test update of data in database before actual update. There is some complex transformation on columns that requires PHP, so can't be done by stand along SQL query. There is around 100K of rows

Comment: Sure, but do you need to read all 100K records in order to test that the code works? In most cases, you shouldn't need to.

Comment: @Simba this is on production db and I don't know all occurrences and variations. So I must be 100% sure :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you give console response ? and when you use

```
    /**
     * @return type
    */
    public function getData()
    {...}
```

You should call it like this:

```
/**
* @dataProvider getData
*/
public function testData($fixtures)
{
    $x->someFunction($fixtures['exampleAdress'];
}
```

But i will help you more if i see the error or more about your code, is it ORM or not etc...

@EDIT:

Memory Lack:
`phpunit -d memory_limit=128M`
Or
`php -d memory_limit=<memory>M -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit`);"

Comment: Hi @Hikaryu, there is no error in code but only the problem with memory consumption. For example if I put limit in query and return only 1000 rows everything goes well. If I don't set the limit test is Killed by OS.

Comment: aaaaa ok... sorry i understand it wrong way. Have you tried to extend memory limit for test ?
please use this and replay:
`php -d memory_limit=256M -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit');"` 
OR  this:    
 `ini_set('memory_limit', '512M')`

Comment: ah forgot about: `phpunit -d memory_limit=<memory>M`

Comment: memory limit is set to -1, process is killed by OS. I will try some other things also. Thanks